# should I release NSString instance I didn't create?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

For example, string was returned from `NSDictionary`, which in turn read it from file system.
So, we don't know whether string was created through `[NSString stringWith...]` or `[[NSString alloc] initWith...]` or in any other way.

How do you generally know whether you are responsible for releasing returned object, if API doesn't mention it?

PS I've seen similar questions here, but mostly they deal with constants `@""` or explicitly created strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Cocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). If you can only afford to read a single part of the documentation, this is the one :) And there’s also the static analyzer (Build → Build and Analyze) that’s pretty good with the memory-management rules, it should be able to catch what you miss.

Comment: Other answers seem to oversimplify it, but this article is really useful, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, you should only release instances that you've `alloc`'d, `retain`'d, `copy`'d or `new`'d.

Comment: So, I don't need to manage any object I get from another method, ever, right?

Comment: Only if the name of that method contained/started with `copy`, `new`, etc.

Comment: if you're unsure, retain it before you use it and release it as soon as you're done with it.

Comment: That will just result in a leak on objects where you *were* supposed to release them.

Answer (score 1):

The Objective-C rule of thumb: if your code performs an alloc/copy/retain to initialize an object, then you need to release it as you are the owner.  If you do not perform an alloc/copy/retain to initialize an object (such as using a method to get an instance), then you are not the owner and should not release the object.

In this event, you did not create the string, so you are not responsible for releasing it.  You do not need to worry how the string was initialized when it was created and added to the NSDictionary (unless you are creating and adding it to the dictionary yourself).  With most collection objects, they take ownership of the objects that are added to them and so they are responsible for releasing the objects in their care.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation!  If we extend your example, wouldn't me getting string out of dictionary, keeping it as object's attribute and disposing dictionary break this model? Dictionary is the owner, but it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: The model is a bit off, because you don’t have to use `retain` to *initialize* an object, you can also *assume responsibility* over an existing object using `retain`. That’s precisely your example with the dictionary – when you `retain`, you are responsible to `release`. Just like with the fox when you tame it :)

Answer (score 1):

Members of a dictionary are accessed via `-objectForKey:`, so you are not responsible for releasing them. The dictionary was the only object in this example that you directly created. If you did so via an `alloc`, `copy`, or `new` method (e.g. `[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:…]`) then you must release it. If it came from somewhere else including one of the `[NSDictionary dictionary…]` factories, you own no references to it and do not need to release it.